# Google Cloud Load Balancer URL limit?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I've been in a process of migrating our application to use `Gateway` (`gke-l7-global-external-managed`).

Part of deployment are the 'review' applications, e.g.

```yaml
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  labels:
  # {{ include "app.resource_labels" . | indent 4 }}
  name: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - namespace: contra
      sectionName: https
      name: contra-gateway
  hostnames:
    - web-app-{{ .Values.app.deployment.slug }}.contra.dev
  rules:
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /
    backendRefs:
      - name: '{{ .Release.Name }}'
        port: 80
        kind: Service
```

Every review application has a custom sub-domain and custom URL paths.

We have *many* review applications that exist in parallel, and I've hit the following limit when trying to deploy them using `gke-l7-global-external-managed`:

```yaml
- lastTransitionTime: "2023-08-18T23:17:20Z"
  message: 'error cause: gceSync: generic::failed_precondition: Update: Value
    for field ''resource.pathMatchers[50]'' is too large: maximum size 50 element(s);
    actual size 88.'
  observedGeneration: 1
  reason: ReconciliationFailed
  status: "False"
  type: Reconciled
```

How am I supposed to leverage `Gateway` for an application that has thousands of URL path rules when the [Quota](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#url_maps) is set to just 50?

There appears to be a related feature request that's been open since 2019 with not much activity.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/126946582

However, I feel like I am missing something crucial here. Is there an abstraction that should live between `Gateway`/`HTTPRoute`/my application that I am missing?

Comment: Hi \`Gajus\` can you elaborate what type of abstraction you are trying to have in between gateway and your application, so that we can provide an accurate solution. Regarding the feature request part try to upvote the existing one so that it might be addressed quickly by the google team.

Comment: None. The expectation was that I can use `Gateway` to setup `HTTPRoute`s, which would point to `Service`s.